# kernprof wont profile my code

Tags: python, debugging, line-profiler

I'm trying to profile my code and I cannot figure out why kernprof isn't working. I've run examples and they work just fine however my code just hangs. Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

u = ['a','b','c','d']
pc = ['1,23,6,12',
      '2,51,42',
      '3',
      '72,7,2,8']

@profile
def stuff(users, pixels_csv):
    network = nx.Graph()

    for user, pixels in zip(users, pixels_csv):
        pixels = pixels.split(',')
        pixel_combinations = combinations(pixels, 2)

        for edge in pixel_combinations:

            e0 = edge[0]
            e1 = edge[1]
            network.add_edge(e0, e1)

            try:
                if (e0, e1) in network.edges():
                    network[e0][e1]['weight'] += 1

            except KeyError:
                network[e0][e1]['weight'] = 1


        for node in network.nodes():
            if node in pixels:
                try:
                    if user not in network.node[node]['unique_users']:
                        network.node[node]['unique_users'].append(user)

                except KeyError:
                    network.node[node]['unique_users'] = [user]

    return network.nodes()

stuff(u, pc)
```

I've tried the following commands and nothing happens, net.py in on my desktop.

```
comp:Desktop k$ kernprof -l -v net.py

comp:Desktop k$ python /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kernprof.py -l -v net.py
```

this example works with this command:

```
comp:Desktop k$ python /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kernprof.py -l -v primes.py
```

file called: primes.py

```
@profile
def primes(n): 
    if n==2:
        return [2]
    elif n<2:
        return []
    s=range(3,n+1,2)
    mroot = n ** 0.5
    half=(n+1)/2-1
    i=0
    m=3
    while m <= mroot:
        if s[i]:
            j=(m*m-3)/2
            s[j]=0
            while j<half:
                s[j]=0
                j+=m
        i=i+1
        m=2*i+3
    return [2]+[x for x in s if x]
primes(100)
```

Comment: code runs fine now I had a small error from refactoring the code for this post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: With your revised code, I cannot see any reason it would not work.

Comment: Yeah I've been scratching my head for a couple hours I don't know whats going wrong

Comment: Does it work on other scripts?

Comment: yeah I tested an example (added to post)